# What's the meaning of 'call in aid'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

> > [[Source:]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlill_v_Carbolic_Smoke_Ball_Co#Lord_Justice_Lindley) We must first consider whether this was intended to be a promise at all, or whether it was a mere puff which meant nothing. Was it a mere puff? My answer to that question is No, and I base my answer upon this passage: “£1000. is deposited with the Alliance Bank, shewing our sincerity in the matter.” Now, for what was that money deposited or that statement made except to negative the suggestion that this was a mere puff and meant nothing at all? The deposit is **called in aid** by the advertiser as proof of his sincerity in the matter — that is, the sincerity of his promise to pay this £100. in the event which he has specified. I say this for the purpose of giving point to the observation that we are not inferring a promise; there is the promise, as plain as words can make it.
>
> **[call something in](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/call)** = 5. 
>       Require payment of a loan or promise of money:

Definition 5 seems wrong; how does it make sense for the advertiser to require payment of his own deposit?

Answer (score 1):

> The deposit is called in aid by the advertiser as proof of his sincerity in the matter — that is, the sincerity of his promise to pay this £100.

I guess the meaning is:

> Mentioning the existence of this deposit, the advertiser sought to prove his sinserity in the matter, that is, the sincerity of his promise to pay this L100

My guess is that we can read "the deposit was called in aid" roughly as "the deposit was invoked (used) in order to help". Or "was resorted to".

Compare:

> ... To an action of assault against several of the yeomanry cavalry, **called in aid** of the civil power at Manchester; ([1825](https://books.google.ru/books?id=NEJKAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22called%20in%20aid%22&hl=ru&pg=RA3-PA20#v=onepage&q=%22called%20in%20aid%22&f=false))

Someone **called** a cavalry company **in aid** (as a helping force) of the civil authorities of Manchester. To rephrase,

> The cavalry company was **called in aid** by somebody as a force able to help keep civil order in Manchester.

I can say that

> The Google Books service was **called in aid** by CopperKettle as means to find out the meaning of the expression "to call in aid".